# Put items in DynamoDB without knowing the attributes

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

This feels like a really stupid question, but my lack of JS knowledge combined with lack of AWS knowledge has me in a tight spot! I'm just trying to get to grips with a basic AWS stack i.e. Lambda/Dynamo/API Gateway for some basic API work.

If I want a simple API endpoint to handle PUT requests e.g. `https://my.endpoint.amazonaws.com/users`. If I have a DynamoDB table with a composite primary key of `userID` and `timestamp` I could use the code snippet below to take the unknown data (attributes that weren't known when setting a schema), but this obviously doesn't work well

```
const dynamo = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();
let requestJSON = JSON.parse(event.body);
await dynamo
  .put({
    TableName: "myDynamoTable",
    Item: {
      userID: requestJSON.userID,
      timestamp: requestJSON.timestamp,
      data: requestJSON.data
    }
  })
.promise();
```

I could send a `PUT` request with the following JSON

```
{
    "userID": "aaaa1111",
    "timestamp": 1649677057,
    "data": {
        "address": "Elm Street",
        "name": "Glen"
    }
}
```

but then `address` and `name` get shoved into a single DynamoDB attribute named `data`. How do I construct the `node` code to create a new attribute named `address` and one named `name` with the corresponding values, if I didn't know these attributes i.e. I want to use JSON in my request like below, but assuming I don't know this and can't use `requestJSON.address`

```
{
    "userID": "aaaa1111",
    "timestamp": 1649677057,
    "address": "Elm Street",
    "name": "Glen"
}
```

Comment: Why do you have a composite primary key of userID and timestamp? Do you have a use case for historical versioning of user items?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [spread](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) operator, for example:

```js
const data = {
  address: "Elm Street",
  name: "Glen",
};

const item = {
  userID: "aaaa1111",
  timestamp: 1649677057,
  ...data,
};

console.log("item:", item);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you insist on the API contract as

```js
{
    "userID": "aaaa1111",
    "timestamp": 1649677057,
    "data": {
        "address": "Elm Street",
        "name": "Glen"
    }
}
```

then you can do mapping on the TypeScript level

```js
const request: {userID: string, timestamp: number, data: any} = {
    "userID": "aaaa1111",
    "timestamp": 1649677057,
    "data": {
        "address": "Elm Street",
        "name": "Glen"
    }
};

const ddbObject: any = {
    "userID": request.userID,
    "timestamp": request.timestamp
};

Object
    .keys(request.data)
    .forEach(key => ddbObject[key] = request.data[key]);
```

Representation of `ddbObject` is

```js
{
  "userID": "aaaa1111",
  "timestamp": 1649677057,
  "address": "Elm Street",
  "name": "Glen"
}
```